# Colorear fila donde celda tenga valor de arraylist

Tags: java, jtable

Lo que quiero hacer es: Colorear las filas de una tabla donde la celda en la columna x tenga un valor presente en un arraylist.

Más detalladamente:
Lleno el array list con los valores `1000000, 1000001, 1000007` de una consulta a la base de datos.

Ahora, recorro todas las filas de la columna x y, si el valor que tienen es igual a uno de los que está en el arraylist, entonces se colorea.

Suena fácil, pero no logro que se pinten las celdas con dichos valores, sólo se colorea la celda donde el index del arraylist es el más (alto en este caso el 2 o sea el 1000007)

Código:

```
public static class solic_proc extends DefaultTableCellRenderer{
@Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table,value,isSelected,hasFocus,row,column);

int i=0;
for(i=0; i<lista.size(); i++){
if(table.getValueAt(row, 0).toString().equals(String.valueOf(lista.get(i)))){
setBackground(Color.GREEN); 
      }else{
                  setBackground(new Color(255,255,255));
                   setForeground(new Color(1,70,148));
     }

}
```

Comment: Gracias, desde el móvil no puedo hacer eso.

Comment: ¿Has probado a poner en la sentencia if:  table.getValueAt(row, column)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agrega la linea break; luego del setBackground(Color.GREEN); para que salga del for en el momento de colorear y no continue evaluando todos los valores del array.

Comment: Voy a intentarlo, gracias!

Comment: Gracias me ha funcionado!

Comment: Podes indicar que la respuesta es correcta y votarla con flecha arriba si te sirvió. Saludos!